# Meaning and etymology of the expression “棒棒的！”

Tags: meaning, mandarin, etymology, meaning-in-context

Someone wrote to me "两个月就写这么好，棒棒的！"

I get the first part (though I don't think it's true - 哪里哪里 ；-））, but what exactly does that "appendix" stand for? I interpreted it as a kind of "clapping one's hands in approval", as Google Translate just spits out "Bang Bang!", but that may well be too far-fetched!

Any input on this?

Comment: 棒 means great. 棒棒的 is just the duplication of the adjective.

Comment: It means 'great' said by a cute girl. That means If a guy talk to me" 你写的棒棒的'. I may reply "When have you been to be a gay"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

棒 means 'great; awesome'.

棒棒 the repetition basically makes it sound rhythmical and cute.

的 after a repeated adjective in spoken language is a very subtle thing - it slightly changes the meaning from 'awesome' (praising your writing) to 'keep being awesome' (encouraging you).

Overall, the difference between (真)棒 and 棒棒的 is like that between '(very) cool' and 'cool beans' in English.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence written this way to expressing one's feeling, and there are different ways to do this. You can understand it as if the person writing is adding in feelings in their words, like using different tones when speaking.

From the first part of the sentence, you can tell this approach is self praise style and acting cute whilst doing it. So in this case the person is trying to say "I'm great", but doing it in a cute way. "棒" means great/nice/awesome as @enrico explained already. "棒棒的" is like rather than saying "爸" (Dad) one might say "爸爸" (also Dad). It does not change any mean here. The reason why I am saying it makes the person saying this sound cute is because when kids are younger, they would say "Daddy" and once they are older they will chan say "Dad" instead.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks! However, she didn't praise herself, but was rather giving me a compliment for my writing.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense too. The power of ambiguity :)

Answer (score 1):

棒棒的 is a cute way to say "good", "well" and something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It's really a 琼瑶 question!

My experience is that the term used by those can't pronounce 儿音 like 真棒儿，真带劲儿 instead they can only say each separately 真-带-劲-儿. I used to have a friend from Taiwan, for the life of her, she could not say 一会儿 the way we say in mandarin.

Comment: 谢谢，这是真带劲儿了! :-)